# Trace embedding for derivatives (Sobolev spaces)

Tags: sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces, trace-map

It is given in Evans and almost all other PDE books that the trace operator for a bounded domain $\Omega$ with $C^1$ boundary

(*) $\gamma:H^1(\Omega)\rightarrow L^2(\partial\Omega)$

is continuous i.e, $\|\gamma u\|_{L^2(\partial\Omega)}\leq C \|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}$.

I was wondering if this result could be extended to

$\gamma:H^2(\Omega)\rightarrow H^1(\partial\Omega)$

is continuous i.e, $\|\gamma u\|_{H^1(\partial\Omega)}\leq C \|u\|_{H^2(\Omega)}$.

The above result assertion seems correct to me as I have increased the regularity equally by 1 in (*). I was reading about fractional sobolev spaces. The result I have read is that for a Lipschitz domain $\Omega$ and $\frac{1}{2}< s<\frac{3}{2}$ we have the following continuous trace operator,

$\gamma:H^s(\Omega)\rightarrow H^{s-\frac{1}{2}}(\partial\Omega)$

Now if I can take $s=\frac{3}{2}$ then it would follow easily as ,

$\|\gamma u\|_{H^1(\partial\Omega)}\leq C \|u\|_{H^\frac{3}{2}(\Omega)}\leq C\|u\|_{H^2(\Omega)}$

However $s<\frac{3}{2}$.

I have just started reading about fractional sobolev spaces, traces and extensions operator. So I am not quite sure about some of the results. Thanks for any help.

Comment: How do you define $H^1(\partial\Omega)$?

Comment: I am under the assumption$\|\gamma u\|_{H^1(\partial\Omega)}^2=\int_{\partial\Omega}|\gamma u|^2 +\int_{\partial\Omega} |\gamma Du|^2$.

Comment: I was reading the book Elliptic problems in non smooth domain by Grisvard. In theorem 1.5..1.1 it states then given some condition the mapping $u\rightarrow\lbrace\gamma u,\gamma Du,\cdots,\gamma D^ku\rbrace$ is a unique continuous extension operator from $W_p^s$ onto $\prod_{j=0}^kW_p^{s-j-\frac{1}{p}}$. I am trying to understand this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, there exists a trace operator $H^2(\Omega) \to H^1(\Omega)$ provided $\Omega$ is sufficiently regular. The follwing theorem holds (see,e.g, Theorem 3.37 in *Strongly Elliptic Systems and Boundary Integral Equations* by McLean): If $\Omega $ is a $C^{k-1,1}$ domain, and if $\frac 12 < s \leq k$, then there exists a linear and bounded trace operator $\gamma \colon H^s(\Omega) \to H^{s -  \frac 12}(\partial \Omega)$. Moreover, there exists a continuous right inverse of $\gamma$.

Comment: Thanks you so much this is exactly what I was looking for. It is my understanding now that if $\Omega$ is Lipschitz (k=1) then I do not have the continuous embedding $H^2(\Omega)\rightarrow H^1(\partial\Omega)$. In order for to have $H^2(\Omega)\rightarrow H^1(\partial\Omega)$ i will require $k=\frac{3}{2}
$. I hope this is correct. Thanks for the help.

Comment: As far as I know, you don't have the continuous embedding $H^2(\Omega) \to H^1(\partial \Omega)$ if $\Omega$ is only a $C^{0,1}$ domain. But if $\Omega$ is a $C^{1,1}$ domain, then this continuous embedding exists.